# Converting a visual studio makefile to a linux makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

i am new to makefiles and have just rescently created a makefile that works for a c++ project. it has two cpp files and one h file. i am trying to convert my file to work in linux but cant seem to figure out how. any ideas?

```
EXE = NumberGuessingGame.exe
CC = cl
LD = cl
OBJ = game.obj userInterface.obj
STD_HEADERS = header.h
CFLAGS = /c
LDFLAGS = /Fe

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)$(EXE)

game.obj: game.cpp $(STD_HEADERS)
    $(CC) game.cpp $(CFLAGS)

userInterface.obj: userInterface.cpp $(STD_HEADERS)
    $(CC) userInterface.cpp $(CFLAGS)

#prepare for complete rebuild
clean:
    del /q *.obj
    del /q *.exe
```

Comment: big one: there's no `del` in linux. or .exe...

Comment: its rm right? instead of del

Comment: Which tools do you have on the linux platform? (If you're not sure, try `make -v` and `g++ -v`.)

Comment: Also, the object file extension is `.o` (not `.obj`) and options are specified with a dash, not a slash. (And it's unlikely the compilers are option-compatible; `-Fe` might not at all be the options you want.)

Comment: Make already knows how to compile and link, so all you really need are the dependencies which cannot be inferred, and any option overrides you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For in depth treatment of make on Linux, see [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

There are a few differences. Binaries have no extension

```
EXE = NumberGuessingGame
```

The compiler is `gcc`, but need not be named, because `CC` is built in, same goes for `LD`. But since your files are named `.cpp`, the appropriate compiler is `g++`, which is `CXX` in make.

Object files have extension `.o`

```
OBJ = game.o userInterface.o
STD_HEADERS = header.h
```

Compiler flags

```
CXXFLAGS = -c
```

The equivalent for `/Fe` is just `-o`, which is not specified as `LDFLAGS`, but spelled out on the linker command line.

Usually, you use the compiler for linking

```
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE)
```

You don't need to specify the rules for object creation, they are built in. Just specify the dependencies

```
game.o: $(STD_HEADERS)
userInterface.o: $(STD_HEADERS)
```

`del` is called [`rm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html)

```
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

One important point is, indentation is one *tab* character, *no* spaces. If you have spaces instead, make will complain about

```
*** missing separator.  Stop.
```

or some other strange error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) to accomplish your task:

Put following into CMakeLists.txt file in the root directory of your project (`<project-dir>`):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (NumberGuessingGame)
add_executable(NumberGuessingGame game.cpp serInterface.cpp)
```

Then on the console do

- "in-source" build

  ```
  $ cd <project-dir>
  $ cmake .
  $ make
  ```
- or "out-source" build

  ```
  $ mkdir <build-dir>
  $ cd <build-dir>
  $ cmake <project-dir>
  $ make
  ```

You can adjust build setting using nice GUI tool. Just go to the build directory and run `cmake-gui`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include headers in the dependency list. The compiler will fail on its own, stopping make from continuing. However, if you're including them in the dependency list to force make to rebuild files in case the header changes, nobody will stop you.

CFLAGS never needs to contain -c, nor does LDFLAGS need -o. Below is a revamped makefile. Note that you can always override a macro explicitly defined in a makefile or implicitly defined using something like `make CFLAGS=-Wall` for example. I used the de facto standard CXX macro name in the event that you have C source files, which must be compiled using a C compiler (the value of the CC macro) instead of a C++ compiler.

```
.POSIX:

#CC is already implicitly defined.
CXX = g++
OBJ = game.o userInterface.o
STD_HEADERS = header.h

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp .c

NumberGuessingGame: $(OBJ) $(STD_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

.cpp.o: $(STD_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

#There is already an implicit .c.o rule, thus there is no need for it here.

#prepare for complete rebuild
clean:
    -rm -f NumberGuessingGame *.o
```

As yegorich answered, you can use a build system like Cmake. It is much more flexible, cross-platform, and can generate Unix Makefiles as well as Nmake Makefiles and Visual Studio solutions on Windows.