# simple Makefile for c program

Tags: c, makefile

I have this (working) Makefile for single-file C-Application.

```
all: simpleua

simpleua: simpleua.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`
```

now I want to extend this Makefile for a multiple-file C-Application.
The files are main.c simpleua.c simpleua.h

I have found some samples on the Internet but nothing simple and working with pkg-config

Thanks alot
florian

Comment: You might find the section on using `wildcards` in the `make` manual useful.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654948/converting-a-visual-studio-makefile-to-a-linux-makefile/21656515#21656515) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This may take a few iterations (and you've left out a lot of details). Try this:

```
all: simpleua

simpleua: simpleua.o main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`

simpleua.o main.o: %.o: %.c simpleua.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs libproject`
```

**EDIT:** second try (with thanks to Jonathan Leffler). The use of `--libs` in the pattern rule may be unnecessary, but try it and see.

Comment: thanks for the reply! but I get alot of 'undefined reference to' errors with that Makefile

Comment: You need the `pkg-config --libs libpjproject` at least in the link line; you arguably should not include `--libs` in the line that creates the object files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thank you, I'm not familiar with pkg-config and was going by the online docs; I'll edit. (I said it might take a few iterations.)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple example `Makefile` for you

```
CC = gcc
XX = g++
CFLAGS = -g

INC := -I test.h

$(LIBS)

TGT = ./sample
OUTPUT = ../output/

%.o: %.c    
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c *.cpp)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES)))

$(TGT) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(TGT)    
    chmod 777 $(TGT)
    cp $(TGT) $(OUTPUT)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ $(OUTPUT)/*
```

It works for both C and C++ for this you just need change from CC to XX.
For example purpose i have two directory  as in `Makefile`

```
1)sample 

2)output
```

In sample directory all my source resides and in output folder my final binary copied (you can give any name to directory as you want but make sure you also give same name in `Makefile` ).so you can put as many source file in sample directory and able to compile it.