# Include Makefile into qmake, inheriting properties

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

**Aim**

I would like to start a Qt project using another C++ project as starting point that I put in a subdirectory.

Inside `/Qt Project/C++ sub-project` there is a Makefile with its definition and variables and flags and the source (in different subdirs).

I would like the qt-project to include this makefile and be able to compile all the objects of the sub-project and link them together (with their flags and libs) in the new project.

**Attempts**

I tried to make use, inside the .pro,
`mytarget.commands = make -C ./sub-project -f makefile`,
but this simply uses the makefile, and thus cannot link together with the new main source code that uses Qt.

I tried to link separately all the sub-project in a single object, but `ld` or `ar` does not recognize flags.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative approach**

Have you tried [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)? Just make a central `CMakeLists.txt` file with all definitions you need and then include `CMakeLists.txt` files, that you put in either folder Qt and C++. This way you'll have a consistent configuration without mixing `Makefiles` and `qmake` stuff.

Here you'll find a [Qt + CMake tutorial](https://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects).

Comment: this imply I must rewrite the makefile?

Comment: Have you looked at the links I've posted in my answer? You'll have to replace your makefile with CMake's CMakeLists.txt. CMake has it's own meta-language to describe build configuration. It processes CMakeLists.txt and creates Makefiles. You'll automatically get clean targets etc. It provides some helper blocks for Qt for example to include Network library etc. One more [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Qt). This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654948/converting-a-visual-studio-makefile-to-a-linux-makefile/21656515#21656515) has CMake invocation example.

Comment: thanks, but if possible I prefer not to rewrite the makefile, even though CMake seems pretty effective and I definetely will it take into account on my future personal projects.